# Added a UITableView programmatically, can't select a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am adding a tableview to my view controller with this method

```
func addTableView() {
    tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, tableViewWidth, defaultHeaderY))
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    tapMapViewGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.mapViewTapped(_:)))// when header is tapped
    tapTableViewGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.tableViewTapped(_:)))// when when tableView itself is tapped
    tapTableViewGesture!.delegate = self
    tableView.tableHeaderView!.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapMapViewGesture!)
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapTableViewGesture!)
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.allowsSelection = true
    view!.addSubview(self.tableView)

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "HomeCell", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeCell")
}
```

I want to add an action upon cell selection so I implemented the following method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("did select")
}
```

But nothing is being printed out when I select a cell. Did I miss something when I added the table view programmatically?

Comment: remove tap gesture

Comment: why you've added gesture in Tableview ?
its overriding the default method didSelectRowAtIndexPath.
thats why its not getting called.

Comment: did you implemented the **cellForRowAtIndexPath** and **numberOfRowsInSection**

Comment: `tapTableViewGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.tableViewTapped(_:)))// when when tableView itself is tapped`  I think,this gesture prevent the cellSelected method.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the tap gestures. You guys are all geniuses